# Intellij Idea wrongly marking maven project source folder

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am migrating java modules to maven. With these changes I used the maven project structure. But IDE (Intellij Idea) is not correctly marking source root, resource root, tests root etc. It marks **/src** as the source root instead of **/src/main/java**. I am using java 17. In pom I have specified in properties to use maven.compiler.release of the same version as java (17).

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

I am not sure what details are needed to sort this issue, I'll add them later. I've tried multiple guides, but nothing is working for me. If I mark the folders manually, it stays that way until I reload maven project. I was expecting Idea to mark folder automatically.

Folder after I manually set source root and resource root.
[image]

The folder looks like this after maven reload.

[image]

Comment: close IJ, delete `.idea` folder and open it in IJ as "new project" to refresh all first import procedure. Basically a "turn it off and on again" approach !

Comment: @StefanoRiffaldi Thank u for the suggestion, that I've done that. I deleted .idea and .iml files from the project and tried to configure it again. Sadly same result.

Comment: have you tried right-clicking on those directories and altering the configuration there?

Comment: @Stultuske Thank you for the suggestion. Yeah I've tried that, the folders looks like in the picture above after maven reload.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? Ideally a minimal `pom.xml`  that reproduces this issue?

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thank you for the suggestion. When I created new project in Idea using Maven Archetype with `maven-archetype-archetype` I wasn't able to reproduce the issue. Is there a way to somehow set existing project to this archetype?

Comment: @Fleky you've put it as having two root source folders

Comment: @Stultuske Thank you for the suggestion. I've added how I've set the folder and how they look after maven reload.

Comment: @Fleky: does it work when you copy just the pom.xml from your existing project into a new folder and import that? Basically what you'd need to do is cut out as much of your current pom.xml until the problem is not reproducible and then re-add the last thing that was cut out.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thank you for the suggestion. I found the issue. I had badly defined build section in pom. There was reference to `sourceDirectory` src. Instead of the src/main/java.

Comment: Remove the definition `sourceDirectory` completely ... not necessary nor usefull...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you for the suggestion. Should there be something else instead? In the build section?

Comment: No ... the directories are convention...https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html